# Bluemix: Java application logs are not displaying in bluemix

Tags: java, spring, logging, ibm-cloud, slf4j

I have a Spring application which is usin Slfj Logger. When the application is deployed to bluemix the logs are not getting displayed. I am not sure what configuration are required to display the logs in bluemix.:

logback.xml:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was not able to see the logs generated by my application. So I used socket-appender to direct my logs to a virtual machine or a docker container with Centos Image. You cannot directly see the logs generated by your application. 
Check this, if it helps- 
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/monitor_log/monitoringandlogging.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the best practice for logging of Bluemix Java applications is to write the logs to STDOUT and have Loggregator drain the logs or use services like [Monitoring and Analytics](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/monana/index.html#monana_la_tab_oview) to help you to search the log files that your application generated in the previous 24 hours, identify errors, and graph search results.

Your slf4j configuration file seems OK to me, I'd just try to lower the log level to one that considers the logs you're writing (DEBUG for example).